# How to create Quadtree Copy constructor with Recursion

Tags: c++, tree, quadtree

I am working on a copy constructor for a Quadtree. Here's what I have so far:

```
    //Copy Constructor
    Quadtree :: Quadtree(const Quadtree & other)
    {
    root = copy(other.root);
    resolution = other.resolution;
    }

   //Copy Constructor helper function
    Quadtree::QuadtreeNode *Quadtree :: copy (const QuadtreeNode* newRoot)
    { 
    if (newRoot != NULL)
    {
        QuadtreeNode *node = new QuadtreeNode(newRoot->element);
        node->nwChild = copy(newRoot->nwChild);
        node->neChild = copy(newRoot->neChild);
        node->swChild = copy(newRoot->swChild);
        node->seChild = copy(newRoot->seChild);

        return node;    
    }
    else
        return NULL; 
     }
```

I'm not sure where I am going wrong, but I am receiving memory leaks and Valgrind is pointing out that I have uninitialized values. Help please?

Attached, is my buildTree function - where I actually create the tree. I may be doing something wrong here?

```
    void Quadtree :: buildTree (PNG const & source, int theResolution)
    {
        buildTreeHelp (root, 0, 0, theResolution, source);  
    }

   void Quadtree :: buildTreeHelp (QuadtreeNode * & newRoot, int xCoord, int yCoord, int d, PNG const & image)
    {
       if (d == 1)
       {
            RGBAPixel pixel = *image(xCoord, yCoord);
            newRoot = new QuadtreeNode(pixel);
            return; 
       }
        newRoot = new QuadtreeNode ();
        newRoot = NULL;

            buildTreeHelp(newRoot->nwChild, xCoord, yCoord, d/2, image);
        buildTreeHelp(newRoot->neChild, xCoord + d/2, yCoord, d/2, image);
        buildTreeHelp(newRoot->swChild, d/2, yCoord + d/2, d/2, image);
        buildTreeHelp(newRoot->seChild, d/2 + xCoord, d/2 + yCoord, d/2, image);
    }
```

Comment: Can you post a small **complete** example?  The code you've provided is not evidence enough of memory leaks or uninitialized access.

Comment: I added the buildTree function which actually builds the tree. Perhaps there is something wrong in the way I initialized the tree?

Answer (score 1):

I think the memory leak lies here:

```
    newRoot = new QuadtreeNode ();
    newRoot = NULL;
```

You are allocating memory then setting the pointer to `NULL` without deallocating the memory.  Also, on the next line you are trying to dereference the pointer that you just set to NULL:

```
    buildTreeHelp(newRoot->nwChild, xCoord, yCoord, d/2, image);
```

You would likely benefit from using a smart pointer such as `std::unique_ptr` to manage memory instead of using raw calls to `new` and `delete`.